# PyTorch model + HTTP API = very slow execution

Tags: http, machine-learning, pytorch, fastapi

I have:

- ML model (PyTorch) that vectorizes data and makes a prediction in **~3.5ms** (median ≈ mean)
- HTTP API (FastAPI + uvicorn) that serves simple requests in **~2ms**

But when I combine them, the median response time becomes almost **200ms**.

**What can be the reason for such degradation?**

---

Note that:

- I also tried aiohttp alone, aiohttp + gunicorn and Flask development server for serving - same result
- I tried to send 2, 20 and 100 requests per second - same result
- I do realize that parallel requests can lead to decreased latency, but not 30 times!
- CPU load is only ~7%

---

Here's how I measured model performance (I measured the median time separately, it's nearly the same as the mean time):

```py
def predict_all(predictor, data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        predictor(data[i])

data = load_random_data()
predictor = load_predictor()
%timeit predict_all(predictor, data)
# manually divide total time by number of records in data
```

Here's FastAPI version:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from my_code import load_predictor

app = FastAPI()

app.predictor = load_predictor()


@app.post("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    predictor = request.app.predictor
    data = await request.json()
    return predictor(data)
```

HTTP performance test:

```
wrk2 -t2 -c50 -d30s -R100 --latency -s post.lua http://localhost:8000/
```

**EDIT.**

Here's a slightly modified version which I tried with and without `async`:

```py
@app.post("/")
# async def root(request: Request, user_dict: dict):
def root(request: Request, user_dict: dict):
    predictor = request.app.predictor
    start_time = time.time()
    y = predictor(user_dict)
    finish_time = time.time()
    logging.info(f"user {user_dict['user_id']}: "
                 "prediction made in {:.2f}ms".format((finish_time - start_time) * 1000))
    return y
```

So I just added logging of prediction time.

Log for async version:

```
2021-02-03 11:14:31,822: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 2.87ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49284 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,329: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 3.93ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49286 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,345: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 15.06ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49287 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,351: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 4.78ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49288 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,358: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 6.85ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49289 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,363: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 3.71ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49290 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,369: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 5.49ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49291 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:14:56,374: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 5.00ms
```

So prediction is fast, less than 10ms on average, but whole request takes 200ms.

Log for sync version:

```
2021-02-03 11:17:58,332: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 65.49ms
2021-02-03 11:17:58,334: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 23.05ms
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49481 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49482 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
2021-02-03 11:17:58,338: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 72.39ms
2021-02-03 11:17:58,341: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 78.66ms
2021-02-03 11:17:58,341: user 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123: prediction made in 85.74ms
```

Now prediction takes long! For whatever reason, exactly the same call, but made in synchronous context, started to take ~30 times longer. But the whole request takes approximately the same time - 160-200ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In endpoints that does highly intensive calculations and which presumably takes longer when compared to the other endpoints, use a non-coroutine handler.

When you use `def` instead of `async def`, by default FastAPI will use `run_in_threadpool` from Starlette and which also uses `loop.run_in_executor` underneath.

`run_in_executor` will execute the function in the default loops executor, it executes the function in a seperate thread, also you might want to check options like [`ProcessPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) if you are doing highly CPU intensive work.

This math simple math helps a lot when working with coroutines.

```
function
   if function_takes ≥ 500ms
       use `def`
   else
       use `async def`
```

Making your function non-coroutine should do good.

```py
@app.post("/")
def root(request: Request):
    predictor = request.app.predictor
    data = await request.json()
    return predictor(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried sync and async, and added intermediate measurements - please see the edited post.

Comment: That's very interesting, the OS Scheduler's and the thread's overhead shouldn't be adding x30 latency. ~3.5ms for prediction is neat, using coroutines is better in your case.   But i still can't wrap it up in my head why non-coroutine endpoint is x30 slower.

Comment: Note that the sync and async _endpoints_ have approximately the same latency, this is predictor.__call__ which is different. It looks like extreme context switching (although 2rps shouldn't do it anyway) or using CPU time for something totally unrelated to the prediction. Weird.

Comment: After many experiments and fine-tuning we've finally achieved good performance using a single async server (no gunicorn workers) and `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Though, I still can't explain why multiple workers don't work and additional processes do.

Answer (score 0):

I observed similar problems.

I started fastAPI with --reload

```
uvicorn app:webapp --port 3030 --reload
```

removing **--reload** solved the problem

```
uvicorn app:webapp --port 3030
```